# Is there a way to split the text I'm inputting into different strings that the dictionary looks at individually

Tags: python, string, nlp

I am mostly trying to create software that reads says the definition of every word you typed into the text box. Right now it only reads if there is one work and crashes if there is more than one. How would I go about fixing this?

```
import wolframalpha
client = wolframalpha.Client('8QR2WG-628657K83Q')

from multiprocessing import Process

import wikipedia

import PySimpleGUI as sg

import cv2

import random

import sys
import threading
import time

import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')

# from oxforddictionaries.words import OxfordDictionaries
# Oxford = OxfordDictionaries('b4170561','f32687e0ecbc219cfd723bb220dad34e')
# o = OxfordDictionaries('b4170561','f32687e0ecbc219cfd723bb220dad34e')
# relax = o.get_synonyms("Apple").json()
# synonyms = relax

from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
nltk.download("stopwords")
stop_words = set(stopwords.words("english"))
filtered_list = []

from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')

stemmer = PorterStemmer()


trained_face_data = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
trained_body_data = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_upperbody.xml')
trained_eye_data = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')
webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
sg.theme('graygraygray')

layout = [  [sg.Text("Enter Test Text")],
            [sg.Input()],
            [sg.Button('Ok')] ]
window = sg.Window('You', layout)


sg.Popup('About Me','Hello I am an AI devolped by Garrett Provence. I will be using your webcam to scan your suroundings for a quick few seconds and will open a text box where you will be able to ask me questions. By clicking ok below you agree to letting me acess everyhting said before. I am still in beta so please be patient.')

timeout = time.time() + 10;


while True:


##Webcam scanner
    def infiniteloop1():
        while True:
            test = 0
            if test == 5 or time.time() > timeout:
                break
            test = test - 1


            successful_frame_read, frame = webcam.read()

            grayscaled_img = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

            face_coordinates = trained_face_data.detectMultiScale(grayscaled_img)
            body_coordinates = trained_body_data.detectMultiScale(grayscaled_img)
            eye_coordinates = trained_eye_data.detectMultiScale(grayscaled_img)


            for (x,y,w,h) in face_coordinates:
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y),(x+w, y+h), (0,random.randrange(255),0), 2)
            for (x,y,w,h) in body_coordinates:
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y),(x+w, y+h), (0,0,255), 2)
            for (x,y,w,h) in eye_coordinates:
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y),(x+w, y+h), (random.randrange(255),0,0), 2)
            cv2.imshow('FaceThing',frame)
            cv2.waitKey(1)

    thread1 = threading.Thread(target=infiniteloop1)
    thread1.start()
    event, values = window.read()
    InputText = values[0]


    import json
    import requests
    import os
    import pprint
    import Oxfordwords
    from Oxfordwords import Word
    import pprint



##end OF webcam scanner

#img = cv2.imread('Rdj.png')
    while True:


            ##Test Text Scanner --
            Text = values[0]
            Word.get(Text)
            if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Cancel':
                break
                sys.exit()
            try:
                words_in_excerpt = word_tokenize(Text)

                nltk.pos_tag(words_in_excerpt)
                print('Hello',nltk.pos_tag(words_in_excerpt), "")
                sg.Popup('Test', nltk.pos_tag(words_in_excerpt))
                sg.Popup('Def',Word.definitions())
                break
            except:
                sg.Popup('There seems to be a error processing what you have said')
                break
            ##End of test Text Scanner --
```

The oxford dictonary code -

```
#!/bin/env python3


""" oxford dictionary api """

from http import cookiejar

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup


class WordNotFound(Exception):
    """ word not found in dictionary (404 status code) """
    pass


class BlockAll(cookiejar.CookiePolicy):
    """ policy to block cookies """
    return_ok = set_ok = domain_return_ok = path_return_ok = lambda self, *args, **kwargs: False
    netscape = True
    rfc2965 = hide_cookie2 = False


class Word(object):
    """ retrive word info from oxford dictionary website """
    entry_selector = '#entryContent > .entry'
    header_selector = '.top-container'

    title_selector = header_selector + ' .headword'
    wordform_selector = header_selector + ' .pos'
    property_global_selector = header_selector + ' .grammar'

    br_pronounce_selector = '[geo=br] .phon'
    am_pronounce_selector = '[geo=n_am] .phon'
    br_pronounce_audio_selector = '[geo=br] [data-src-ogg]'
    am_pronounce_audio_selector = '[geo=n_am] [data-src-ogg]'

    definition_body_selector = '.senses_multiple'
    namespaces_selector = '.senses_multiple > .shcut-g'
    examples_selector = '.senses_multiple .sense > .examples .x'
    definitions_selector = '.senses_multiple .sense > .def'

    extra_examples_selector = '.res-g [title="Extra examples"] .x-gs .x'
    phrasal_verbs_selector = '.phrasal_verb_links a'
    idioms_selector = '.idioms > .idm-g'

    other_results_selector = '#rightcolumn #relatedentries'

    soup_data = None

    @classmethod
    def get_url(cls, word):
        """ get url of word definition """
        baseurl = 'https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/'
        return baseurl + word

    @classmethod
    def delete(cls, selector):
        """ remove tag with specified selector in cls.soup_data """
        try:
            for tag in cls.soup_data.select(selector):
                tag.decompose()
        except IndexError:
            pass

    @classmethod
    def get(cls, word):
        """ get html soup of word """
        req = requests.Session()
        req.cookies.set_policy(BlockAll())

        page_html = req.get(cls.get_url(word), timeout=5, headers={'User-agent': 'mother animal'})
        if page_html.status_code == 404:
            raise WordNotFound
        else:
            cls.soup_data = soup(page_html.content, 'html.parser')

        if cls.soup_data is not None:
            # remove some unnecessary tags to prevent false positive results
            cls.delete('[title="Oxford Collocations Dictionary"]')
            cls.delete('[title="British/American"]')  # edge case: 'phone'
            cls.delete('[title="Express Yourself"]')
            cls.delete('[title="Collocations"]')
            cls.delete('[title="Word Origin"]')

    @classmethod
    def other_results(cls):
        """ get similar words, idioms, phrases...
        Return: {
                'All matches': [
                    {'word1': word1, 'id1': id1, 'wordform1': wordform1},
                    {'word2': word2, 'id2': id2, 'wordform2': wordform2}
                    ...
                    ]
                'Phrasal verbs': [
                    {'word1': word1, 'id1': id1, 'wordform1': wordform1},
                    {'word2': word2, 'id2': id2, 'wordform2': wordform2}
                    ...
                    ]
                ...
                }
        """
        info = []

        try:
            rightcolumn_tags = cls.soup_data.select(cls.other_results_selector)[0]
        except IndexError:
            return None

        # there can be multiple other results table like All matches, Phrasal verbs, Idioms,...
        header_tags = rightcolumn_tags.select('dt')
        other_results_tags = rightcolumn_tags.select('dd')

        # loop each other result table
        for header_tag, other_results_tag in zip(header_tags, other_results_tags):
            header = header_tag.text
            other_results = []

            for item_tag in other_results_tag.select('li'):
                names = item_tag.select('span')[0].find_all(text=True, recursive=False)
                wordform_tag = item_tag.select('pos')
                names.append(wordform_tag[0].text if len(wordform_tag) > 0 else '')
                other_results.append(names)

            other_results = list(filter(None, other_results))  # remove empty list
            ids = [cls.extract_id(tag.attrs['href'])
                   for tag in other_results_tag.select('li a')]

            results = []
            for other_result, id in zip(other_results, ids):
                result = {}
                result['name'] = ' '.join(list(map(lambda x: x.strip(), other_result[0:-1])))
                result['id'] = id

                try:
                    result['wordform'] = other_result[-1].strip()
                except IndexError:
                    pass

                results.append(result)

            info.append({header: results})

        return info

    @classmethod
    def name(cls):
        """ get word name """
        if cls.soup_data is None:
            return None
        return cls.soup_data.select(cls.title_selector)[0].text

    @classmethod
    def id(cls):
        """ get id of a word. if a word has definitions in 2 seperate pages
        (multiple wordform) it will return 'word_1' and 'word_2' depend on
        which page it's on """
        if cls.soup_data is None:
            return None
        return cls.soup_data.select(cls.entry_selector)[0].attrs['id']

    @classmethod
    def wordform(cls):
        """ return wordform of word (verb, noun, adj...) """
        if cls.soup_data is None:
            return None

        try:
            return cls.soup_data.select(cls.wordform_selector)[0].text
        except IndexError:
            return None

    @classmethod
    def property_global(cls):
        """ return global property (apply to all definitions) """
        if cls.soup_data is None:
            return None

        try:
            return cls.soup_data.select(cls.property_global_selector)[0].text
        except IndexError:
            return None

    @classmethod
    def get_prefix_from_filename(cls, filename):
        """ get prefix (NAmE or BrE) from audio name when prefix is null """
        if '_gb_' in filename:
            return 'BrE'

        elif '_us_' in filename:
            return 'NAmE'

        return None

    @classmethod
    def pronunciations(cls):
        """ get britain and america pronunciations """
        if cls.soup_data is None:
            return None

        britain = {'prefix': None, 'ipa': None, 'url': None}
        america = {'prefix': None, 'ipa': None, 'url': None}

        try:
            britain_pron_tag = cls.soup_data.select(cls.br_pronounce_selector)[0]
            america_pron_tag = cls.soup_data.select(cls.am_pronounce_selector)[0]

            britain['ipa'] = britain_pron_tag.text
            britain['prefix'] = 'BrE'
            america['ipa'] = america_pron_tag.text
            america['prefix'] = 'nAmE'
        except IndexError:
            pass

        try:
            britain['url'] = cls.soup_data.select(cls.br_pronounce_audio_selector)[0].attrs['data-src-ogg']
            america['url'] = cls.soup_data.select(cls.am_pronounce_audio_selector)[0].attrs['data-src-ogg']
        except IndexError:
            pass

        if britain['prefix'] == None and britain['url'] is not None:
            britain['prefix'] = cls.get_prefix_from_filename(britain['url'])

        if america['prefix'] == None and america['url'] is not None:
            america['prefix'] = cls.get_prefix_from_filename(america['url'])

        return [britain, america]

    @classmethod
    def extract_id(cls, link):
        """ get word id from link
        Argument: https://abc/definition/id
        Return: id
        """
        return link.split('/')[-1]

    @classmethod
    def get_references(cls, tags):
        """ get info about references to other page
        Argument: soup.select(<selector>)
        Return: [{'id': <id>, 'name': <word>}, {'id': <id2>, 'name': <word2>}, ...]
        """
        if cls.soup_data is None:
            return None

        references = []
        for tag in tags.select('.xrefs a'):  # see also <external link>
            id = cls.extract_id(tag.attrs['href'])
            word = tag.text
            references.append({'id': id, 'name': word})

        return references

    @classmethod
    def references(cls):
        """ get global references """
        if cls.soup_data is None:
            return None

        header_tag = cls.soup_data.select(cls.header_selector)[0]
        return cls.get_references(header_tag)

    @classmethod
    def definitions(cls, full=False):
        """ Return: list of definitions """
        if cls.soup_data is None:
            return None

        if not full:
            return [tag.text for tag in cls.soup_data.select(cls.definitions_selector)]
        return cls.definition_full()

    @classmethod
    def examples(cls):
        """ List of all examples (not categorized in seperate definitions) """
        if cls.soup_data is None:
            return None
        return [tag.text for tag in cls.soup_data.select(cls.examples_selector)]

    @classmethod
    def phrasal_verbs(cls):
        """ get phrasal verbs list (verb only) """
        if cls.soup_data is None:
            return None

        phrasal_verbs = []
        for tag in cls.soup_data.select(cls.phrasal_verbs_selector):
            phrasal_verb = tag.select('.xh')[0].text
            id = cls.extract_id(tag.attrs['href'])  # https://abc/definition/id -> id

            phrasal_verbs.append({'name': phrasal_verb, 'id': id})

        return phrasal_verbs

    @classmethod
    def _parse_definition(cls, parent_tag):
        """ return word definition + corresponding examples
        A word can have a single (None) or multiple namespaces
        Each namespace can have one or many definitions
        Each definitions can have one, many or no examples
        Some words can have specific property
        (transitive/intransitive/countable/uncountable/singular/plural...)
        A verb can have phrasal verbs
        """
        if cls.soup_data is None:
            return None

        definition = {}

        try:  # property (countable, transitive, plural,...)
            definition['property'] = parent_tag.select('.grammar')[0].text
        except IndexError:
            pass

        try:  # label: (old-fashioned), (informal), (saying)...
            definition['label'] = parent_tag.select('.labels')[0].text
        except IndexError:
            pass

        try:  # refer to something (of people, of thing,...)
            definition['refer'] = parent_tag.select('.dis-g')[0].text
        except IndexError:
            pass

        definition['references'] = cls.get_references(parent_tag)
        if not definition['references']:
            definition.pop('references', None)

        try:  # sometimes, it just refers to other page without having a definition
            definition['description'] = parent_tag.select('.def')[0].text
        except IndexError:
            pass

        definition['examples'] = [example_tag.text
                                  for example_tag in parent_tag.select('.examples .x')]

        definition['extra_example'] = [
            example_tag.text
            for example_tag in parent_tag.select('[unbox=extra_examples] .examples .unx')
        ]

        return definition

    @classmethod
    def definition_full(cls):
        """ return word definition + corresponding examples
        A word can have a single (None) or multiple namespaces
        Each namespace can have one or many definitions
        Each definitions can have one, many or no examples
        Some words can have specific property
        (transitive/intransitive/countable/uncountable/singular/plural...)
        A verb can have phrasal verbs
        """
        if cls.soup_data is None:
            return None

        namespace_tags = cls.soup_data.select(cls.namespaces_selector)

        info = []
        for namespace_tag in namespace_tags:
            try:
                namespace = namespace_tag.select('h2.shcut')[0].text
            except IndexError:
                # some word have similar definitions grouped in a multiple namespaces (time)
                # some do not, and only have one namespace (woman)
                namespace = None

            definitions = []
            definition_full_tags = namespace_tag.select('.sense')

            for definition_full_tag in definition_full_tags:
                definition = cls._parse_definition(definition_full_tag)
                definitions.append(definition)

            info.append({'namespace': namespace, 'definitions': definitions})

        # no namespace. all definitions is global
        if len(info) == 0:
            info.append({'namespace': '__GLOBAL__', 'definitions': []})
            def_body_tags = cls.soup_data.select(cls.definition_body_selector)

            definitions = []
            definition_full_tags = def_body_tags[0].select('.sense')

            for definition_full_tag in definition_full_tags:
                definition = cls._parse_definition(definition_full_tag)
                definitions.append(definition)

            info[0]['definitions'] = definitions

        return info

    @classmethod
    def idioms(cls):
        """ get word idioms
        Idioms dont have namespace like regular definitions
        Each idioms have one or more definitions
        Each definitions can have one, many or no examples
        """
        idiom_tags = cls.soup_data.select(cls.idioms_selector)

        idioms = []
        for idiom_tag in idiom_tags:

            try:
                # sometimes idiom is in multiple idm classes inside
                # one idm-l class instead of a single idm class
                idiom = idiom_tag.select('.idm-l')[0].text
            except IndexError:
                idiom = idiom_tag.select('.idm')[0].text

            global_definition = {}

            try:  # label: (old-fashioned), (informal), (saying)...
                global_definition['label'] = idiom_tag.select('.labels')[0].text
            except IndexError:
                pass

            try:  # refer to something (of people, of thing,...)
                global_definition['refer'] = idiom_tag.select('.dis-g')[0].text
            except IndexError:
                pass

                global_definition['references'] = cls.get_references(idiom_tag)
            if not global_definition['references']:
                global_definition.pop('references', None)

            definitions = []
            # one idiom can have multiple definitions, each can have multiple examples or no example
            for definition_tag in idiom_tag.select('.sense'):
                definition = {}

                try:  # sometimes, it just refers to other page without having a definition
                    definition['description'] = definition_tag.select('.def')[0].text
                except IndexError:
                    pass

                try:  # label: (old-fashioned), (informal), (saying)...
                    definition['label'] = definition_tag.select('.labels')[0].text
                except IndexError:
                    pass

                try:  # refer to something (of people, of thing,...)
                    definition['refer'] = definition_tag.select('.dis-g')[0].text
                except IndexError:
                    pass

                definition['references'] = cls.get_references(definition_tag)
                if not definition['references']:
                    definition.pop('references', None)

                definition['examples'] = [example_tag.text for example_tag in definition_tag.select('.x')]
                definitions.append(definition)

            idioms.append({'name': idiom, 'summary': global_definition, 'definitions': definitions})

        return idioms

    @classmethod
    def info(cls):
        """ return all info about a word """
        if cls.soup_data is None:
            return None

        word = {
            'id': cls.id(),
            'name': cls.name(),
            'wordform': cls.wordform(),
            'pronunciations': cls.pronunciations(),
            'property': cls.property_global(),
            'definitions': cls.definitions(full=True),
            'idioms': cls.idioms(),
            'other_results': cls.other_results()
        }

        if not word['property']:
            word.pop('property', None)

        if not word['other_results']:
            word.pop('other_results', None)

        if word['wordform'] == 'verb':
            word['phrasal_verbs'] = cls.phrasal_verbs()

        return word
```

Any help will be appreciated thank you:)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just split `values[0]` into words and call `Word.get(...)` on each

```py
import re

while True:
    ##Test Text Scanner --
    words = re.findall(r"\w+", values[0].strip()) # can also use nltk.word_tokenize
    for word in words:
        Word.get(word)
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Cancel':
            break
    
        try:
            words_in_excerpt = word_tokenize(Text)
            nltk.pos_tag(words_in_excerpt)
            print('Hello', nltk.pos_tag(words_in_excerpt), "")
            sg.Popup('Test', nltk.pos_tag(words_in_excerpt))
            sg.Popup('Def', Word.definitions())
            break
        except:
            sg.Popup('There seems to be a error processing what you have said')
            break
```